# jQuery Menu doesn't collapse/close on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

The mobile menu opens and closes fine on PC. But on mobile devices the menu opens fine, but doesn't close. Can somebody take a look at my jQuery code below and make sure it is good. I am using the code on WP.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".genesis-nav-menu > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $(".genesis-nav-menu li ul").slideUp(350);
      $(".genesis-nav-menu li a").removeClass("open");
      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: First things first, you do not need to check to see that the JQuery element both does not have and has a class. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Can you make one? Just add your code to a JS fiddle, alongside the HTML you're using.